# How to overload Add for computational graph nodes in Rust

Tags: reference, rust, operator-overloading

I am creating a computational graph, a program that models equations as graphs so they can be differentiated, for example. I have overloaded operators so that adding graph nodes creates new graph nodes. However, I find myself fighting the borrow checker. Here's the code:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Expr<'a> {
    Constant(f32),
    //       ^^^--this is a simplified version. In the real version,
    //            Constant holds large matrices and I would like to 
    //            avoid copying it. 
    Add(&'a Node<'a>, &'a Node<'a>),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
    pub body: Expr<'a>
}

impl<'a> Add for &'a Node<'a> {
    type Output = Node<'a>;
    fn add(self, other: &'a Node<'a>) -> Node<'a> {
        Node { body: Expr::Add(self, other) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Node { body: Expr::Constant(1.) };
    let f: Node = &(&a + &a) + &a;
    println!("f: {:#?}", f);
}
```

As you can see, `+` needs to take two `graph::Node` struct references and return a `graph::Node` struct. Because `&(&a + &a)` gets created and dies in the same line, I get this error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:20
   |
25 |     let f: Node = &(&a + &a) + &a;
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^     - temporary value only lives until here
   |                    |
   |                    temporary value created here
26 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

I am using references because I want to avoid copying `Node` structs. The code here is slightly simplified; in the version I'm working with, these can hold a lot of data.

I've tried static references and `Rc` pointers and had no success. When I try to use `Rc` pointers, the compiler complains about overloading `Add`:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
  --> function.rs:86:1
   |
86 | impl Add for Rc<Function> {
   | ^ impl doesn't use types inside crate
   |
   = note: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate
```

Currently I'm just defining new variables for every operation which is really messy:

```
let f1 = &a + &a;
...
let f = &a + f1
```

What would be ideal is if I could avoid using references altogether (that would make the code a lot cleaner). At the very least, I need some way to generate new nodes from the addition of existing nodes.

Comment: Why not just do what the error message tells you and use a `let` binding? `let f = &a + &a; let f2 = &f + &a;`. Why do you store references to `Node`s in the first place, instead of just storing them directly? Why not implement `Add` for non-references?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Shepmaster. So I am currently using `f1 = ...; f2 =  ...`. It just makes the code difficult to read when you're dealing with a large complicated equation. The reason for storing references is that using add-for non-references would require a copy and that is problematic for performance (I've simplified the code a little, but in the real version, graph Nodes can contain large matrices).

Comment: What went wrong when using `Rc`?

Comment: I wasn't able to overload operators with Rc. I edited the original post with more details.

Comment: @ethanabrooks `Rc` implements `Deref` and `Clone`, so with `Rc` you should be able to write `&foo + &bar` or `foo.clone() + bar.clone()`, depending on whether you implement `Add` for reference or the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by recognizing that `Node` and `Expr` are redundant:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Expr<'a> {
    Constant(f32),
    Add(&'a Expr<'a>, &'a Expr<'a>),
}

impl<'a> Add for &'a Expr<'a> {
    type Output = Expr<'a>;
    fn add(self, other: &'a Expr<'a>) -> Expr<'a> {
        Expr::Add(self, other)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Expr::Constant(1.);
    let f = &(&a + &a) + &a;
    println!("f: {:#?}", f);
}
```

> I am using references because I want to avoid copying `Node` structs. The code here is slightly simplified; in the version I'm working with, these can hold a lot of data.

This is why your code doesn't work. Consider the following perfectly valid implementation of `Add`:

```
fn add(self, other: &'a Expr<'a>) -> Expr<'a> {
    Expr::Constant(42.0)
}
```

Then we call that and return it as the first half of this expression:

```
let f = &(&a + &a) + &a;
//       ^-------- here
```

Where is that `Constant` stored? There's just a temporary value without an owner. When you do the *second* addition, you are trying to take a reference to that that has to live for the entire time that `f` is valid. Except the value will be dropped as soon as that expression is over, because there is nothing to own it. Thus you are prevented from doing anything of the sort.

Additionally, `&'a Expr<'a>` means that the lifetime `'a` has to be the unification of the references lifetime and the contained data's lifetime. This means that `'a` will be shortened to the the life of the `Expr` passed in, which in this case again ends at the end of the statement.

Normally, whenever I see `&'a Foo<'a>`, I think one of two things:

1. That should be `Foo<'a>` — `Foo` is just a wrapper around other types of references and doesn't need to have another reference.
2. That should be `&'a Foo<'b>` — we have references to something which has references, and they have differing lifetimes.

The latter doesn't work here - it's complicated to explain, but ultimately you end up with something like

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Expr<'e, 'd> {
    Constant(f32),
    Add(&'e Expr<'e, 'd>, &'e Expr<'e, 'd>),
}
```

Which *never actually uses the `'d` parameter*!

Doing the first option is fine if you can own the large data outside of your expression hierarchy:

```
use std::ops::Add;

type LargeMatrix = Vec<u8>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Expr<'a> {
    Constant(&'a LargeMatrix),
    Add(Box<Expr<'a>>, Box<Expr<'a>>),
}

impl<'a> Add for Expr<'a> {
    type Output = Expr<'a>;
    fn add(self, other: Expr<'a>) -> Expr<'a> {
        Expr::Add(Box::new(self), Box::new(other))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = LargeMatrix::new();

    let a = Expr::Constant(&m);
    let f = (a.clone() + a.clone()) + a;
    println!("f: {:#?}", f);
}
```

If you want the expression tree to own the large data as well as references to subtrees, then you can use `Rc`, as suggested in the comments. Whenever the data is cloned, only the reference counters are incremented, so no large copies will be made:

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::rc::Rc;

type LargeMatrix = Vec<u8>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Expr {
    Constant(Rc<LargeMatrix>),
    Add(Rc<Expr>, Rc<Expr>),
}

impl Add for Expr {
    type Output = Expr;
    fn add(self, other: Expr) -> Expr {
        Expr::Add(Rc::new(self), Rc::new(other))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Expr::Constant(Rc::new(LargeMatrix::new()));
    let f = (a.clone() + a.clone()) + a;
    println!("f: {:#?}", f);
}
```

You could then choose to implement addition for references:

```
impl<'a> Add for &'a Expr {
    type Output = Expr;
    fn add(self, other: &'a Expr) -> Expr {
        Expr::Add(Rc::new(self.clone()), Rc::new(other.clone()))
    }
}
```

And the other two variants (`&Expr + Expr`, `Expr + &Expr`) if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help and suggestions. I didn't realize that cloning an `Rc` didn't clone the inner values. So I was able to reimplement my code as follows:

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Expr {
    Constant(f32),
    //       ^^^--this is a simplified version. In the real version,
    //            Constant holds large matrices and I would like to 
    //            avoid copying it. 
    Add(Node, Node),  // USED TO BE ADD(&NODE, &NODE)
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)] // CLONE IS NEW
pub struct Node {      
    pub body: Rc<Expr> // CHANGED TO RC
}

// THIS IS NEW
impl Add for Node {
    type Output = Node;
    fn add(self, other: Node) -> Node { &self + &other }
}

impl<'a> Add for &'a Node {
    type Output = Node;
    fn add(self, other: &Node) -> Node {
        Node { 
          body: Rc::new(Expr::Add(self.clone(), other.clone()))
      }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Node { body: Rc::new(Expr::Constant(1.)) };
    let f: Node = &a + &a + a; // <-- basically, the desired outcome
    println!("f: {:#?}", f);
}
```

It would be nice if I could somehow get rid of the `&`s in the definition of `f`, but the only way seems to be to implement `Copy`. Unfortunately, this is not possible in the real version because `Node` has an additional field, `output`, with type `Rc<RefCell<Option<Constant>` where `Constant` is an enum . I know, not the best, but unfortunately I need aliased mutability and that seems to be the only way. Anyway, this monster of a type can't implement `Copy`. Any ideas on that front are welcome, but otherwise, thanks for your help!